# getMethodASTEclipse() returns undeclared variable

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, rascal

I am completely new to Rascal and am trying to create ASTs from an eclipse project using the following code

```
Module FirstTryAST
import lang::java::m3::Core;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
import Set;
import Relation;
import IO;  
import List;
import Map;
import Exception;
import ParseTree;

void test(){
    M3 myModel = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://MyProject/|);
    println("Loaded M3 model, looping through methods..");

    for(m <- methods(model)) mAST = getMethodASTEclipse(m);

    println("Success");
}
```

When the program (run in eclipse Rascal Console) tries to execute

`getMethodASTEclipse(m);`

it returns:

> |plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/lang/java/jdt/m3/Core.rsc|(1238,18,<40,12>,<40,30>):
>   Undeclared variable: getModelContaining

How do I get around this / what did I do wrong ?

I am using Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 15.04 (Cinnamon).
If you need more information, please let me know.

> Update:

When I use `getMethodASTEclipse(m, model = myModel)` it works fine.
Although this workaround works for me, I still would like to know the answer on why I get this undeclared variable message.

Comment: Looks like this slipped through the tests and the code is simply still buggy. The static checker is done soon, so these things can't happen anymore in a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been translated into an [issue on github](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/906). This was a bit of an unused function, and I think we will delete it.

To get the AST use either `lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::createAstsFromEclipseProject` or `lang::java::jdt::m3::AST::createAstsFromEclipseFile`. With rascal pattern matching you can find the methods inside.